# What's the best way to merge external changes into my Git repo?

Tags: git

I have a project in a Git repo and I have been sent changes that have been made outside of Git. These changes are based on an earlier version that I have been making changes to myself. What is the best way to merge these external files with mine?

Many thanks!

Comment: In what format were these changes sent to you? A diff file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way is to tell git what commit they were based off of, to give you the best chance of an automatic merge.

1. `git checkout <sha1 of the old commit> -b mybranch`, to rewind your work tree and start a new branch.
2. If the changes were sent as a diff, use `git-apply` to apply them to the work tree, otherwise just put the updated files in.
3. Add and commit the files.
4. `git checkout master`, then `git merge mybranch`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this sounds like what I want. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to act exactly as if you were working with these files, so commit them from the state of the earlier version you're talking about:

1. Create a branch at the commit you believe to be the base of the modified file
2. Add the modified file
3. Commit
4. Merge back the branch to your main development branch

Comment: I'm doing this but git would just overwrite the changes, not merging them, so I cannot handle any merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be for person who provided the changes to give a patch instead of files. But if it is not possible, that other person is not Version Control aware or something else, you could try commit all your outstanding changes in the branch you're currently working on. Preferrably try to avoid any untracked files as well. Then copy over those files into the git repo and run `git status` and you will see what are the changes comparing to the state of your repo, and then you can decide what you will do with them