# Merge changes from clearcase label to git branch

Tags: git, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are using clearcase and git for version control.
I have a situation where my fellow colleague has released few changes in a developer label in clear case. Now i want to pull those particular changes to git branch.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make a snapshot view with a config spec selecting that label.

Then from your separate git working tree folder, do

```
git --work-tree=path/to/snapshot/view add .

# or, to limit files added:
git --work-tree=path/to/snapshot/view add -- afile
git --work-tree=path/to/snapshot/view add -- a folder
```

That will instruct git to add files modifications from your snapshot view.

Comment: this adds all the files. Can we pick only files which we need and see what is getting merge. With lot of files it becomes difficult to analyze

Comment: @Daemon Sure: I have edited the answer. Just add those files (without doing a commit). If you don't like what you see, you always can reset the Git working tree.

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot. But going through the process I realized as the changes shared from clear case are from outside of git world, this was more or less comparing two files and auto merge. Correct me if I am wrong.
Also these answers helped http://stackoverflow.com/a/505130/2045438 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5810874/2045438
Also is there a way to open a merge tool with git --work-tree

Comment: @Daemon Correct: git add will do a (2-way) merge by default. You can also launch a compare tool (kdiff3 or other) and check for the diff yourself.